# Journal / Proceeding about comparing the similarity of 2 images?

Tags: image, matlab, journal

I am a newbie in Matlab field. And i want to learn more about methodology to comparing 2 images to know the similarity between them.

I need more information in international journal / international proceeding, book or another reprort that describe about it.

I Will use it as my literature study.

Is there any suggestion what is the similar journal,book or proceeding that has discussed about it? If has, please include the title and link of them..

Thank You for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

For journals I would recommend the IEEE Transactions on Image Processing:

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=83

This is a good general intro from MIT:

http://www.mit.edu/~ka21369/Imaging2012/tannenbaum.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "similarity" better.

In the image compression sense, similarity is a function of the pixel-wise difference between the images ([PSNR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio), and other metrics).

In a computer vision sense, you would want to see if the two images contain similar content such as objects or scenes. I would recommend using [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=content%20similarity%20images&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0,15) for that.